# php класс для icq

Tags: php, icq

Потребовалось добавить в icq чат бота который периодически бы писал сообщения. 
Попробовал несколько решений на php из сети, но все они очень старые и не заработали. 
Может подскажет кто рабочий вариант для обмена сообщений в ** групповой чат-**icq.

C Уважением, Waik

Comment: Из нового вы врятли что-нибудь найдете, боты для icq очень старая тема

Comment: Понимаю. В этом и проблема)
С другой стороны - протокол icq думаю не изменялся достаточно долгое время

Comment: На PHP вряд ли, а вот на Java тут (https://sourceforge.net/projects/exeqlib/). Хотя на Гитхабе кое-что есть, но древнее (https://github.com/topics/icq?l=php), как раз бот для ICQ.

Comment: Спасибо, но на java тоже старенькое, 2013 год)

Answer (score 0):

Использую библиотеку WebIcqPro.class.php [ссылка на github](https://github.com/asminog/WebIcqPro). Вроде работает.